# Which force to resolve?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

[image]

In the above image the particle is effectively moving 'out of the page' in circular motion. We want to solve for $\alpha$, the slope is smooth, and the particle is moving neither up nor down the slope.

Which is correct? $R\cos \alpha = mg$ or $R = mg \cos \alpha$?

If we say $R\cos \alpha = mg$ and $R\sin\alpha = \frac{mv^2}{r}$ then we can solve for $\alpha$ by dividing. This gives the correct answer. However, I am having trouble understanding the first of these two equations. The problem is that, in a statics problem involving a mass sitting on a ramp (the same diagram without the $\frac{mv^2}{r}$) we would use the equation $R=mg\cos\alpha$, and I cannot see why there should be a difference.

Comment: What is $R$? I see where you drew it, but what is giving rise to it? Is it a force?

Comment: Its the normal reaction force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: $R \neq mg\cos(\alpha)$, because there is a component of $\frac{mv^2}{r}$ in the same direction.

**Relative to horizontal and vertical**

[image]

The horizontal force must be equal to resultant force towards the center of the circle (for circular motion).
$$
R \sin(\alpha) = \frac{mv^2}{r} \\ 
$$
The particle is in equilibrium in the vertical direction, so
$$
R \cos(\alpha) = mg
$$
Then, like you said, you can divide to get the correct answer
$$
\frac{R\sin(\alpha)}{R\cos(\alpha)} = \frac{v^2}{gr}, \quad \tan(\alpha) = \frac{v^2}{gr} \quad \therefore \quad \alpha= \arctan(\frac{v^2}{gr})
$$

**Relative to the slope**

[image]

The horizontal force must be equal to the horizontal component of the resultant force towards the center of the circle.
$$
mg\sin(\alpha) = \ F_{x, net} =  \frac{mv^2}{r}\cos(\alpha) 
$$
Similarly for the vertical, the vertical forces are equal to the vertical component of the resultant force
$$
R - mg\cos(\alpha) =  \frac{mv^2}{r}\sin(\alpha)
$$
You can rearrange the horizontal component easily into the correct answer. 
$$
g\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)} = g\tan(\alpha) = \frac{v^2}{r} \quad \therefore \quad \alpha= \arctan(\frac{v^2}{gr})
$$
So both methods of resolving are equivalent.

Comment: And the reason that its not true here but is in statics is because there is a resultant force?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistype (have edited now). It's true in both, it just depends what you're resolving with respect to.

Comment: How can $R=mg\cos\alpha$ and $R\cos\alpha$ both be true though?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. $R = mg\cos(\alpha)$ is not true, because $mv^2/r$ has a vertical (relative to plane) component.  Am editing my answer now.

Comment: Ok this is fine, but $mv^2/r$ is *not* a force (although you refer to it as such right below your picture). This is like the #1 thing students get wrong in Physics I. You are *not* equating forces, you are using Newton's second law, $\sum F= ma$. Why is the acceleration even there? Because $R$ is making it acceleration towards the center! /rantover

Comment: @levitopher $mv^2/r$ can be thought of as a *resultant* force (it has units of force after all). You're right, I am using $\sum_i \vec{F_i} = m \vec{a} = \frac{mv^2}{r} \hat a$, however we are always using this (even in equilibrium, $\vec{a}=0$) and this is equivalent to equating forces. E.g.
$\sum_i \vec{F_i} = {R\sin(\alpha) \choose R\cos(\alpha)} - {0 \choose mg} =  { mv^2/r \choose 0}$, which yields $R\sin(\alpha) = mv^2/r$ and $R\cos(\alpha) = mg$. Given that the OP is familiar with resultant forces, I skipped that step. Sorry if I have misunderstood your point.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer since you've given it the old college try.

Start by defining a coordinate system in which x is towards the center of the circle and y is upwards. The components of the normal force are
$$R_x=R\sin\alpha,\qquad R_y=R\cos\alpha$$
Then Newton's second law gives you
$$\sum F_x=R\sin\alpha=ma_c=m\frac{v^2}{r}$$
$$\sum F_y=R\cos\alpha-mg=0$$
The second line tells you $R\cos\alpha=mg$ (your first equation), and dividing the first line by this gives you
$$\frac{R\sin\alpha}{R\cos\alpha}=\frac{mv^2}{rmg},$$
which is the correct answer.

Specifically: You know what the acceleration is here, it's $v^2/r$. That acceleration is due to the inwards component of the reaction force $R$. Newton's second law tells us the sum of all the forces is the (mass times the) acceleration. The rest is just math.

Comment: Would this still work if you defined your coordinate system as x going along the plane of the slope and y at right angles?

Comment: Yes.  In short, the two *real* forces, $R$ and $mg$ have to sum vectorially to produce the centripetal force.  You *can* do it the "wrong" way, but it's more work.  It would be equivalent to tilting the frame of reference so that surface is horizontal and the force of gravity points at an angle.  A quick sketch will show you that the centripetal force does not point in a coordinate direction.  You'd have to calculate each component of the centripetal force separately and ... well, don't do it that way.

Comment: Thanks, as Floris said I think my problem was in neglecting the centripetal force when resolving in the direction of the normal reaction force.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally solve this problem with the following diagram:
[image]

The reaction force is normal to the surface, and it's bigger than just the component of gravity because the force provided to the object adds another component. This is the dreaded "centrifugal force" that doesn't exist - except in a rotating frame of reference, where it is a very real "fictitious" force. Once you add that to the diagram, you see that there is a downward force, and a lateral force, that need to be countered by the net reaction force.

You can't simply estimate the reaction force from the gravitational force alone - and that's why you were running into trouble.

See [this link](http://www.batesville.k12.in.us/physics/phynet/mechanics/circular%20motion/banked_no_friction.htm) for some additional analysis of "banked turn" problems.

Comment: The reason I don't really understand this is because it seems you have a component mg acting at right angles to mg, by resolving and then resolving again. Is there any reason why this is allowed in this case?

Comment: I don't like this either, because $mg$ does not point up or to the left.  I understand the analysis, but I think it's more fruitful to realize that the centripetal force has to be the resultant of the two real forces, gravity and the normal force.

Comment: @garyp - see if you like the edited version better...

Comment: @garyp how can the centripetal force be the sum of the two real forces if weight is at right angles to the centripetal force?

Comment: Well ... again, I see what you are after, but the OP is approaching the problem in the fixed frame, not the rotating frame.   There is no centrifugal force in the fixed frame, and it seems to me that introducing it muddies the water.  One could solve the problem in the rotating frame.  I think your diagram is a hybrid of the two frames.

Comment: @bnosnehpets The vertical $mg$ is exactly canceled by the vertical $R\cos\alpha$.   All that remains is the horizontal $R\sin\alpha$, which has to be the source of the centripetal force.

Comment: @garyp - the centrifugal force is something that is quite intuitive: you "feel" it when you swing an object around at the end of a rope. You can say "the reaction force has to be larger to provide the centripetal force" but that is actually less obvious than the argument given by my diagram. "How does it end up larger" is the obvious question that is unanswered by your argument.